# Break a for loop with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

In my node js App, I have a function that checks if you have the permissions:

```
//queryPermissions is an object that contains all possible permissions:
//each property of queryPermission is an object containing the values to be checked
for (var key in queryPermissions) {
    if (queryPermissions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        promisesArray.push(checkThis(key, req.method));
    }
}

Q.all(promisesArray).then(function(response) {
    response.forEach(function(value) {
        //response is an array with all promises' resolved values
        //if all values are true -> access granted
        //if one or more values are false -> access denied
    }
}
```

This works good, but if only one of the values returned by checkThis inside the for loop is false, than the result would be access denied;
so it is not efficient to continue to check other permissions after the first one that resoves with false;
CheckThis returns a promise but sometimes it needs to wait for a query result, sometimes it resolves immediately, it depends.

Is there a way I can break the loop (if it is not finished yet) when the first "checkThis" returns false?

Comment: That beats the purpose of Asynchronicity, isn't it?

Comment: As thefourtheye mentioned you can only do this if you check result after each request and then continue with other requests. That turns your asynchronous code into a synchronous one. I assume that `checkThis` function makes a request to DB (or some other remote server). In that case it would be easier to simply make one request with all permissions to check. In this situation you can optimize on the other end. If you can't alter the other end then I'm afraid you won't make that code more efficient.

Comment: In this case it is not possible to do a single request for all permissions together, since every permission (if needed) has to find some differend data from the db; so the request would be different for everyone in any case...

Comment: You can try to throw an exception in your checkThis. I guess it will stop the flow. But anyway, if all the promises are already ran you hardly save anything.If every call in promise takes significant resources consider to switch to synchronous call as the guys before mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution to Bergi's approach - we map false return values to the exceptional condition failures they are and use `Q.all` directly:

Your current code does:

```
for (var key in queryPermissions) {
    if (queryPermissions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        promisesArray.push(checkThis(key, req.method));
    }
}
```

We add an additional step:

```
for (var key in queryPermissions) {
    if (queryPermissions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        promisesArray.push(checkThis(key, req.method).then(function(val){
             if(!val) throw new Error("Invalid Permissions");
             return true;
        });
    }
}
```

This simple addition would let us use Q directly:

```
Q.all(promisesArray).catch(function(err){
     // one or more authentication errors
}).then(function(){
      // everyone validated, all ok user authenticated here
});
```

This is a more general method - using the exception pipeline for exceptional cases can greatly simplify your code.

Answer (score 2):

Not with any native `Q` function. You could however write an [`every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for promises yourself (loosely based on `Q.all`):

```
Q.every = function every(promises) {
    return Q.when(promises, function (promises) {
        var countDown = 0;
        var deferred = defer();
        for (var i=0; i<promises.length; i++) {
            var promise = promises[i];
            var snapshot;
            if (
                Q.isPromise(promise) &&
                (snapshot = promise.inspect()).state === "fulfilled"
            ) {
                if (!snapshot.value) {
                    deferred.resolve(false);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            } else {
                ++countDown;
                q.when(
                    promise,
                    function (value) {
                        if (!value)
                            deferred.resolve(false);
                        else if (--countDown === 0)
                            deferred.resolve(true);
                    },
                    deferred.reject,
                    (function(index) {
                        return function (progress) {
                            deferred.notify({ index: index, value: progress });
                        };
                    }(i));
                );
            }
        }
        if (countDown === 0) {
            deferred.resolve(true);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort, but if the asynchronous code is already executed, then there is no point in doing this, right?

Comment: The solution I found and posted above works; but in any case this is interesting and can be useful elsewhere...

Comment: @thefourtheye: If one of the promises that yields `false` is faster than the others, we can resolve the resulting promise earlier. Of course, this doesn't abort the other promises (partly because I was too lazy to implement it, partly because Q doesn't support it).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks for the good catch. It was a leftover from the removal of the `reduce_array` call from the [original code](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L1464).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Indeed, `Q.all` run parallel promises, so when you want to break, the other promises are still running. So they can't be stopped. One way is to use `Q.spread` but therefore the promises are no more parallel :(.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I had a sudden enlightment but was not so hard:
just using a global flag:

```
var alreadyFailed = false;

//queryPermissions is an object that contains all possible permissions:
//each property of queryPermission is an object containing the values to be checked
for (var key in queryPermissions) {
    if (alreadyFailed) {
        break;
    }
    if (queryPermissions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        promisesArray.push(checkThis(key, req.method));
    }
}
```

Then it is sufficient to set alreadyFailed to true inside checkThis when a false result occurs;
of course it can happen that the for loop ends before the first resolve to false, but in this case there's no way to do better;
but if checkThis resolves with a false before the for loop ends -> it will be stopped